# How to get text inside of table and iterate multiple

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML in the formal of this

```
 <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td> Test1 </td> 
      <td> .. </td>
    <tr/>
    <tr> ... </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td> Test2 </td> 
      <td> .. </td>
    <tr/>
    <tr> .. </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td> Test3 </td> 
      <td> .. </td>
    <tr/>
    <tr> .. </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I need to have a list of strings Test1, Test2, Test3. I am not quite sure how to iterate through all the tbody's and go in the tr and get the correct td. Could someone point me in the correct direction? How could I generate the xpath into those particular element? They do not have any ids

I was looking into webDriver.findElements(). Could you I use this to iterate through the tbody? If so how?

I tried to do the following:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(..);
WebElement telem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td"));
List<WebElement> tr_collection=telem.findElements(By.cssSelector("td"));
```

This doesn't seem to get all the Test1, Test2, Test3 strings. Unfortunately the HTML doesnt have IDs that I can use. How could I iterate through all these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as Ranjith's, but with Java 8 and xPath:

```
List<String> inOneStatement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")) //List<WebElement> that contains 3 td that hold the desired strings
    .stream().map(WebElement::getText)   //accumulate the outputs from getText of each of those elements
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // return them as List<String>
```

Sorry, didn't check the code in IDE, could have errors.

NB: I would never use this xPath locator in actual test framework, but to build a better one we need more context (full page source).

Comment: Could you help me convert this into Ruby please? I am not quite sure how to do after .stream().map(WebElement::getText) to ruby

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience in ruby. Will check out the manual to see if I can help translate.

Comment: I get StaleelementException with iteration. Any solution for that?

Comment: StaleElementReference exception means that the element that you previously found and now trying to interact with is no longer present, at least in the form it used to. There is a lot of articles online regarding this exception, my favorite is using a proxy pattern that repeats element search several times

Answer (score 1):

Solution for this is:

```
List<String> actualValues = new ArrayList<>();
List<WebElement> tableRowsList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tbody > tr"));
for(WebElement ele: tableRowsList) {
    actualValues.add(ele.findElement(By.cssSelector("td:nth-of-type(1)").getText()));
}
```

Comment: This will work but this is a risky locator to use. If there is any other tables on the page `tbody > tr` will match all the rows from that table aswell. I'd recommend starting by the `table` element. With some luck this has an `id` which can be used to be sure you have the table you want.

Comment: Yes.. that's ideal but code here in the question doesn't have any id's

Comment: @RemcoW if you think it's useful pls give a thumbs up.. Thanks

Comment: I know, I didn't mean it negative. I actually think it's better if you don't do that edit because that way it matcheds the `html` in the question. I just gave it as a tip to anyone that reads this answer ;)

Comment: Rolled back my changes :D

Comment: It cant find .getText()

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
String text = null;

List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Test')]"));

for(WebElement element: allElements){
   text= element.getText();
   System.out.println("Text is : "+text);

}
```

hope this will help you.